# libphonenumber-js evaluates good phone number as false

Tags: javascript, libphonenumber

I'm stumped.

I've messed around with this for a while and it doesn't make sense.

libphonenumber-js does not validate a phone number that should be a valid number.  It returns 'false' every time.

This seems pretty simple and straightforward.  A 10 digit number from a form field.

```
const phoneNumber = libphonenumber.parsePhoneNumber(contact_asset, 'US')

        if (phoneNumber) {
            console.log(libphonenumber.isPossiblePhoneNumber(JSON.stringify(phoneNumber)));
            console.log(phoneNumber.formatNational());

}
```

What seems odd to me is that when I parse the phone number and pass it to the validator, if it's not a string, it complains.  I would expect libphonenumber to accept the output of parse without stringifying it.

What am I missing?

https://jsfiddle.net/TexEvans/sxL28j7h/4/

Comment: Did you ever check what `JSON.stringify(phoneNumber)` returns? It doesn't look like a valid phone number to me.

Comment: I did check it.  It was a valid phone number.  Did you run the fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always take a look at the [documention](https://github.com/catamphetamine/libphonenumber-js#parsephonenumberstring-options-or-defaultcountry-phonenumber)

`parsePhoneNumber` returns `…an instance of PhoneNumber class, or undefined if no phone number could be parsed…`. And you can't expect that `JSON.stringify(phoneNumber)` will result in something that just contains a phone number.

And [isPossiblePhoneNumber](https://github.com/catamphetamine/libphonenumber-js#ispossiblephonenumberinput-string-boolean) expects a string as parameter that is a valid phone number; the documentation states there:

> This function is just a shortcut for a two-step process of "strictly" parsing a phone number and then calling `.isPossible()`.

So what you want to do is either:

```
const contact_asset = "2022032034"
const phoneNumber = libphonenumber.parsePhoneNumber(contact_asset, 'US')

if (phoneNumber) {
  console.log(phoneNumber.isPossible());
}
```

Or

```
const contact_asset = "2022032034"
console.log(libphonenumber.isPossiblePhoneNumber(contact_asset, 'US'));
```

Comment: I read the docs several times before I posted.  I guess I had a typo or something.  Your answer did fix it.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If I format it to international and then check if it's valid, its returning me a valid number, check if this helps.

```
let contact_asset = "2022032034"
const phoneNumber = libphonenumber.parsePhoneNumber(contact_asset, 'US')
const formattedPhoneNumber = phoneNumber.formatInternational()
        
if (phoneNumber) {
    console.log(libphonenumber.isValidPhoneNumber(formattedPhoneNumber));
    console.log(libphonenumber.isPossiblePhoneNumber(formattedPhoneNumber));
    console.log(phoneNumber.formatNational());
}
```